# How to stop the animation scroll of jquery?

Tags: jquery

```js
function valueE(e) {
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  var $radio = $(e.target);

  if ($radio.is('.Fr')) {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
  } else {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numIr').val(newValue);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    validateNresult();
  })


  $('.allrb').change(valueE);


});


function validateNresult() {

  $.each($("tbody tr"), function(i, e) 
  {
    var hasInvalidInputs = $(this).find(".numFr, .numIr").filter(function() {
      return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
    }).length > 0;

    if (hasInvalidInputs) 
    {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
           $('html, body').animate(
            {
             scrollTop: ($(this).offset().top)
            }, 
            1000
        );

    } 

    else {
      $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }

  });

}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 1</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr1" class="numFr" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr1" class="numIr" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 2</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr2" class="numFr" id="numFr2" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr2" class="numIr" id="numIr2" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 3</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir3" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr3" class="numFr" id="numFr3" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr3" class="numIr" id="numIr3" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 4</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir4" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr4" class="numFr" id="numFr4" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr4" class="numIr" id="numIr4" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
<p style="float:right;position:absolute;margin-left:700px;margin-top:10px;" id="alertmessage"></p>
```

If I click to button, the answer that are empty will be highlighted and scroll to the row. But I don't want it scroll row by row,I just want it jump to the first error and no need to scroll row by row. I had try to using the

```
page.on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
       page.stop();
   });
```

but I seem like not work for me. It can be scroll row by row too, but I want it to stop when user scroll down/up their mouse.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scroll to the first invalid row. As its a loop, need to store the first invalid row.

Check the below code. Have changed to store the index of the first invalid row and then scroll to it after loop completes.

NOTE : 20 is subtracted from the top as a buffer, adjust or remove it as per requirement.

Hope this helps!

```js
function valueE(e) {
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  var $radio = $(e.target);

  if ($radio.is('.Fr')) {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
  } else {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numIr').val(newValue);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    validateNresult();
  })


  $('.allrb').change(valueE);


});


function validateNresult() {

  var firstInvalidRowIndex = 0;
  $.each($("tbody tr"), function(i, e) {
    var hasInvalidInputs = $(this).find(".numFr, .numIr").filter(function() {
      return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
    }).length > 0;

    if (hasInvalidInputs) {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
      if (firstInvalidRowIndex <= 0) {
        firstInvalidRowIndex = i + 1;
      }
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }

  });

  if (firstInvalidRowIndex > 0) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($("tbody tr:nth-child(" + firstInvalidRowIndex + ")").offset().top - 20)
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 1</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr1" class="numFr" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr1" class="numIr" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 2</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr2" class="numFr" id="numFr2" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr2" class="numIr" id="numIr2" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 3</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir3" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr3" class="numFr" id="numFr3" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr3" class="numIr" id="numIr3" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 4</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir4" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr4" class="numFr" id="numFr4" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr4" class="numIr" id="numIr4" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>

</table>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
<p style="float:right;position:absolute;margin-left:700px;margin-top:10px;" id="alertmessage"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! This help me, I never know each loop can also use like a for loop.